# How to set the size of a Button in Scala Swing?

Tags: swing, user-interface, scala, button, resize

I'm trying to set the size of a button to a specific size of pixels with `minimumSize`, but it looks like it doesn't work.

I even tried to subclass it and do it this way

```
class SizedButton(text0: String, width0: Int, height0: Int) 
                                      extends Button(text0) {
  minimumSize = new Dimension(width0, height0)
  // also tried preferredSize here ...
}
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: try `this.peer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width0,height0) )` in the class body

Comment: As you know the idiom is to create anonymous subclasses, so creating a named one won't help. Whether minimumSize does anything will depend on which layout manager you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell what you're really trying to do, but generally sizing depends a lot on the layout manager you are using. Anyway the following fixes the size of a button e.g.:

```
import swing._
import java.awt.Dimension

val s = new Dimension(100, 100)
val f = new Frame {
  contents = new FlowPanel { 
    contents += new Button("huhu") { 
      minimumSize = s
      maximumSize = s
      preferredSize = s
    }
  }
}

f.pack
f.visible = true
```

Comment: What fixes it exactly? Setting all three settings or the `f.pack`?

Comment: The pack just sizes the frame to be big enough for the preferredSize of the FlowPanel. The size fixing is done by setting min, max and preferred. In this exact scenario, you can even go without the maxSize, because the FlowLayout won't make the button bigger than its preferred size (because there is no reason to: the free space is taken by the panel).